# Update and renew data based on data in other tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sum, sql-update

There are 3 tables `student`, `course`, and `takes` as following

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
     ID         varchar(5), 
     name       varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     dept_name  varchar(20), 
     tot_cred   numeric(3,0) CHECK (tot_cred >= 0),
     PRIMARY KEY (ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department
        ON DELETE SET NULL
)

CREATE TABLE takes
(
     ID         varchar(5), 
     course_id  varchar(8),
     sec_id     varchar(8), 
     semester   varchar(6),
     year       numeric(4,0),
     grade      varchar(2),
     PRIMARY KEY (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
     FOREIGN KEY (course_id, sec_id, semester, year) REFERENCES section
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES student
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    )

CREATE TABLE course
(
    course_id   varchar(8), 
    title       varchar(50), 
    dept_name   varchar(20),
    credits     numeric(2,0) CHECK (credits > 0),

    PRIMARY KEY (course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department
        ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```

`tot_cred` column data in the `student` table now is assigned with random values (not correct), I want to perform the query that updates and renews those data based on the course's `grade` each student has taken. For those students who received `F` grade will be excluded and those who didn't take any course will be assigned 0 as `tot_cred`.

I came up with two approaches, one is

```
UPDATE student 
SET tot_cred = (SELECT SUM(credits)  
                FROM takes, course  
                WHERE takes.course_id = course.course_id 
                  AND student.ID = takes.ID 
                  AND takes.grade <> 'F' 
                  AND takes.grade IS NOT NULL)
```

This query meets all my needs, but for those students who didn't take any course, it does assign NULL value instead of 0.

The second is using `case when`

```
UPDATE student
SET tot_cred = (select sum(credits)
    case 
         when sum(credits) IS NOT NULL then sum(credits)
         else 0 end
    FROM takes as t, course as c
    WHERE t.course_id = c.course_id
    AND t.grade<>'F' and t.grade IS NOT NULL
)
```

But it assigned 0 to all students. Is any way to achieve the above requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 1st query meets your requirement and the only problem is that it returns `NULL` for the students that did not take any course then the easiest solution would be to use instead of `SUM()` aggregate function the function [`TOTAL()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) which will return `0` instead of `NULL`:

```
UPDATE student AS s 
SET tot_cred = (
  SELECT TOTAL(c.credits)  
  FROM takes t INNER JOIN course c 
  ON t.course_id = c.course_id 
  WHERE t.ID = s.ID AND t.grade <> 'F' AND t.grade IS NOT NULL
);
```

The same could be done with `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(credits), 0)...
```

Also, use a proper join with an `ON` clause and aliases for the tables to improve readability.